# Problem with two variable limit where $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (-1, 8)} xy = -8$ using only definition

Tags: calculus, limits

So we just started with two-variable limits. The definition is quite straight forward though my head is still giving it a few spins. I thought doing a couple of examples would help me. Come the second problem though I've hit a wall.

Consider this.

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (-1,8) } xy = -8$

So I start with the definition. For every epsilon bigger than zero, there has to be a delta bigger than zero such that $\ 0 < ||(x,y) - (-1,8)||_2 < \delta \implies |xy - (-8)|<\epsilon$

But hold and behold. I don't know where to follow from this. In class, the examples given always started trying to use the left hand side part of the inequality of $ \epsilon$ to try and find a bound for $ |xy - (-8) |$. Generally using some absolute value properties and know inequalities like $\ ||X||_ \infty \leq ||X||_2 \leq \sqrt{n} ||X||_2,$ n=elements in X.

But this fails. I don't know what to do with $\ |xy- (-8) | $. 
I can see this will be the same as $\ |x||y|+8 $. But how can I use my hypothesis or some known inequality here to prove the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you want to somehow relate the quantities 
$\vert (x,y)-(-1,8)\vert$ and $\vert xy-(-8)\vert $

in such a way that the latter is small whenever the former is.

With this in mind, write

$\vert xy+8\vert=\vert xy+y-y+8\vert =\vert y(x+1)+(-1)(y-8)\vert \leq \vert y(x+1)\vert +\vert y-8\vert $

and the result follows. More precisely:

let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Take $\delta _{1}=\min \left \{ 1,\epsilon  \right \}$ and $\delta _{2}=\frac{\epsilon }{9}$ and note that if $\vert y-8\vert <\delta _{1}$ then $y<9$.

If we take $\delta =\min \left \{ \delta _{1},\delta _{2} \right \}$ then

$\vert x+1\vert, \vert y-8\vert <\delta \Rightarrow \vert xy+8\vert\leq\vert y(x+1)\vert +\vert y-8\vert =9\frac{\epsilon }{9}+\epsilon =2\epsilon$.

To finish, simply note that if $(x,y)\in B_{\delta }(-1,8)$, then $\vert x+1\vert $ and  $\vert y-8\vert <\delta $

Answer (score 1):

use method like $$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x)-LM|&=|f(x)g(x)-Lg(x)+Lg(x)-LM|\\&=|g(x)(f(x)-L)+L(g(x)-M)|\\&\le|g(x)||f(x)-L|+|L||g(x)-M|\end{align}$$

Comment: Hey. We haven't studied that property yet. And the problem explicitly states that the limit should be proved using *only* the definition of a limit, so this really doesn't go there. unless there's something i'm missing here? thanks :)

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra you definitely did cover the triangle inequality. You can't prove something "just using the definition", you need tools to show that something matches the definition too!

Comment: @avid19 I guess you guys are right, yeah. I'd like to know more about this property first, though. Can I have the name of it? Maybe a link with an explanation + demonstration? Thank you guys really helping me out here.

Comment: just search Limits and Continuity of Functions of Two or More Variables

Comment: @joaquinperryra it's the triangle inequality which is literally impossible for it to not have been covered.